# Фразеологизмы и идиомы

Tags: фразеология

Скажите, пожалуйста, а чем фразеологизм отличается от идиомы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да в общем-то ничем. 
Большинство авторов де-факто употребляют термины как синонимы.
Сталкивался с идеей строго разделить эти понятия по принципу большей или меньшей членимости: значение фразеологизма полагалось частично выводимым из значения составляющих (обычно - одной), идиомы (фразеологического сращения) - полностью невыводимым. Но, насколько понимаю,  реального развития эта идея не получила, поскольку грань очень зыбка.